# php hyperlinks from database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm very new to php and database programs but trying to learn the language and develop a system for my library. I have a database called `booksdb` and two tables called "books" which contains titles of books and author and `bookcatname` which contains categories of books with a unique Category ID.

What I want to do is, display all categories on the page and when one category link is clicked, I want to see the names of books and authors under that particular category displayed on another page,

Example:

```
Art;
    Color and Light by James Gurney
    The Art Spirit by Robert Henry
    How Pictures Work by David Bayles
    Imaginative Realism by James Gurney
```

Here is my code but it does not work.

```
<?php 

  $dbh=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die ('Cannot connedt to the Database' .mysql_errno()); 
  mysql_select_db("booksdb");


  //$res = "SELECT * FROM bookstable GROUP BY category ORDER BY category ASC";
  $res = "SELECT * FROM bookcatname ORDER BY category ASC";


  $res_query = mysql_query($res) or die (mysql_error());
  $ra = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_query);  

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Select a Company</title>
  </head>

  <body>
  <?php do { ?>
    <p><a href="page.php?cat_id=<?php echo $ra['cat_id']; ?>"><?php echo $ra['category']; ?></a></p>
  <?php } while ($ra = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_query))?>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

```
1.Table name - bookcatname
+----+--------+----------+
| id | cat_id | category |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 |      1 | Art      |
|  2 |      2 | Drama    |
|  3 |      3 | Music    |
|  4 |      4 | Fiction  |
|  5 |      5 | Computer |
+----+--------+----------+

2.Table name - books
+----+--------+---------------------------------+-----------------------+
| id | cat_id | title                           | author                |
+----+--------+---------------------------------+-----------------------+
|  1 |      1 | Color and Light                 | James Gurney          |
|  2 |      1 | The Art Spirit                  | Robert Henry          |
|  3 |      1 | Art & Fear                      | David Bayles          |
|  4 |      1 | How Pictures Work               | Molly Bang            |
|  5 |      1 | Imaginative Realism             | James Gurney          |
|  6 |      2 | A Walk To Remember              | Nicholas Sparks       |
|  7 |      2 | An Old Fashioned Girl           | Louisa May Alcott     |
|  8 |      3 | The Rest Is Noise               | Alex Ross             |
|  9 |      3 | It Still Moves                  | Amanda Petrusich      |
| 10 |      3 | Chronicles                      | Bob Dylan             |
| 11 |      3 | Dream Boogie                    | Peter Guralnick       |
| 12 |      3 | Escaping The Delta              | Robert Johnson        |
| 13 |      4 | Atlas Shrugged                  | Ayn Rand              |
| 14 |      4 | Anthem                          | Ayn Rand              |
| 15 |      4 | Sons and Lovers                 | D.H. Lawrence         |
| 16 |      4 | Henderson the Rain King         | Saul Bellow           |
| 17 |      5 | The Art of Computer Programming | Donald Knuth          |
| 18 |      5 | The Art of Unix Programming     | Eric Raymond          |
| 19 |      5 | Free Software, Free Society     | Richard M. Stallman   |
| 20 |      5 | Database System Concepts        | Abraham Silberschatz  |
| 21 |      5 | 3ds Max 2008 in Simple Steps    | Kognet Solutions Inc. |
+----+--------+---------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: You seem to be looking for `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Please also look into MySQLi or PDO as MySQL_* functions are deprecated

Comment: This code should generate the urls properly. You will need another page to display books of that category. Have you already designed such a page?

Comment: should not it be, `WHERE cat_id='$id'`? rewrite the query this way, `$res = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE cat_id='$id'";` and try

Comment: Yes, it is working but it shows only one book title and author under each category. I mean, if category is selected it should show all 5 books under that category.

Comment: Please go ahead and add the code of that file to your question. You're not using any loop if I remember correctly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code to show categories don't work cause your using :

`$ra = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_query);`

and after you do it again in a loop :

`while ($ra = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_query)`

Do only one `while()` to get categories :

```
$getCategories = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bookcatname ORDER BY category ASC");

while ($category = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_query) )
{
  echo '<a href="page.php?cat_id='.$category['cat_id'].'">'.$category['category'].'</a>';
}
```

---

Now, you will need another page to get books from this category (or you can do it in same page).

**books.php**

```
// Same stuff here to connect database

// you check if a category is sent, else you redirect to categories page.
if ( empty($_GET['cat_id']) )
{
  header('Location: index.php');
  exit();
}

// Now you get books from category
// intval() convert to number
$getBooks = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE cat_id = '".intval($_GET['cat_id'])."'");

echo '<ul>';

while ( $book = mysql_fetch_assoc($getBooks) )
{
   echo '<li>'.$book['title'].' by '.$book['author'].'</li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: I am getting this error,

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\xampp\htdocs\books\index.php on line 10

Comment: Dreamweaver shows "There is a syntax error on line 10" (one curly brace is highlighted)

Comment: <pre>
<?php 

$dbh=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die ('Cannot connedt to the Database' .mysql_errno()); 
mysql_select_db("booksdb");


$getCategories = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bookcatname ORDER BY category ASC");

while ($category = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_query)
{
  echo '<a href="page.php?cat_id='.$category['cat_id'].'">'.$category['category'].'</a>';
}


?>

</pre>

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\books\index.php on line 10

Comment: ")" was missing in `while ($category = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_query) )`. Edited.